# Syncing bookmarks between iCloud and Firefox

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, safari, icloud, firefox

I use Windows 7 and I've just got myself a lovely new iPhone. I've installed iCloud and it synchronizes my iPhone's calendar with Outlook, which is great, but I also prefer Firefox over Safari, but iCloud only apparently supports Safari or Internet Explorer (yuck).

Is there any way to sync bookmarks between Firefox/iCloud/iPhone?

Edit: A bit of research brings up a thing called **Firefox Home** - How does this fit in?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/), but this means that you'd have to have Safari or IE open (or at least the Xmarks client for them open) when you're on your desktop.

This way when you add/remove bookmarks from Firefox, Xmarks will bring it over to Safari, then Safari will bring it to iCloud.

Comment: Hmm, I thought if he used XMarks for Firefox it would sync w/o requiring Safari or IE to be open.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/

Comment: Yes, but then the change will be synced to Xmarks, and not to Safari. If it isn't pushed to Safari it won't be pushed to iCloud (thus won't be pushed to his iOS devices).

Comment: I also use XMarks for this and it works great on Mac for Safari. Problem is how XMarks applies the bookmarks does not sync over the cloud to iOS devices. XMarks does have a iOS app but that turns things into a two step process.

Comment: @jtreser, I'm curious to know how the iOS app makes it a two step process.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yeah it is a separate app so on a iOS device it does not sync directly to safari. Previous versions of XMarks for safari on MAC were very unreliable but latest version works well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your goal is to sync your bookmarks across multiple browsers, particularly Firefox on your PC and the built-in Safari browser on your iPhone.

If the use of iCloud isn't a hard requirement (and I don't know why it would be), then use XMarks instead.

1. First, get an XMarks account.
2. Second, install XMarks for Firefox.
3. Third, install XMarks for iPhone.

[1] http://www.xmarks.com/
[2] https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/
[3] http://blog.xmarks.com/2010/08/xmarks-for-iphone-ipad-v127_8748.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can I ask: What's the difference between this and Firefox Home? http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/home/ It seems like it might do the same thing with less installations required.

Comment: I've never used FF Home, but it seems to me that it's FF's version of XMarks.  Pros:  One less install, since it's built in to FF on your PC.  Cons:  Isn't going to work with other browsers.  Both require an account and sync to servers in the Cloud.  I think either would be a good choice.  Let us know how it turns out for you.

Comment: Thanks, James! I'm leaning towards Firefox Home, but I may give them both a shot to see the differences.